# Other way to access http://domain:port

Tags: apache, redirect, localhost, subdomain, port

I currently run an Apache server with Ubuntu 14.04, and also have a TOMCAT server and a Calibre server (running on port 8080 and 8081 respectivly).

I can reach them throught firefox by typing

```
http://localhost:8080 // For TOMCAT
http://localhost:8081 // For Calibre
```

I'd like to know what should I tweak or set to be able to reach them by typing

```
http://tomcat.localhost/ or http://localhost/~user/tomcat
```

and

```
http://calibre.localhost/ or http://localhost/~user/Calibre
```

(I'd like best the first option if possible)

Is this possible to do this without installing a DNS server? (I can use it if needed, but I'd be happier not to use a technology I'm not comfortable with)

I tried a PHP include or redirection in localhost/~user/Calibre/index.php, but this is verry inelegant (and I couldn't get it to work properly anyway)

The goal is to have it used on different computer on my local network (so cross navigators and cross computer compatibility is a better solution, but I'd be happy if it work only on my computer for the moment).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a virtual host to use multiple domain..Follow the article to archive this..Let me know if you have any queries.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: On first look this is most likely what I need, but I see that by using your link, I have to use a fully new domain, which is not what I'm looking for. Do you know any way to do the same thing but for a subdomain?

Comment: http://tomcat.localhost/ and http://calibre.localhost/ are two different domains you have. We have to specify the directory path in .conf file.
Let say tomcat files in /var/www/user/tomcat and calibre files in /var/www/user/tomcat/calibre. Apache will take care of what file to use.. Here domain and sub-domain depends on what directory path you specify..